# Setting uniform y-range for broken axis histogram in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram (using gnuplot (5.4 version)) with broken axis but I am not able to make the y-range uniform in both the plots. For plot where y-range is from [0:-8], the interval is of -1. But for plot where y-range is from [-16:-20], the interval is of -0.5 instead of -1. So is there any way to make the interval uniform in both plots? Any suggestions in that regard will be highly helpful.

Thanks

[image: This is my current output using the below gnu script]

```
set encoding iso_8859_1

set terminal postscript eps enhanced size 5.7, 4.3 color solid linewidth 2 font 'Times-Roman, 22'
set output 'test4.eps'

red = "#FF0000"; green = "#00FF00"; blue = "#0000FF"; skyblue = "#87CEEB";

reset
unset key
bm = 0.05
lm = 0.12
rm = 0.95
tm = 0.5
gap = 0.03
size =0.68
kk = 0.5 # relative height of bottom plot
y1 = 0.0; y2 = -8.0; y3 = -16; y4 = -20
ntics = 5

set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style data histogram
#set key autotitle columnheader
set style fill solid 1.0 border -1

set multiplot
set border 2+4+8
unset xtics
set x2tics nomirror
set x2tics rotate 
#set grid ytics
set ytics nomirror 
set xlabel 'Metals' font 'Times-Roman, 22' offset 0, 16.5;
set ylabel 'd-band' font 'Times-Roman, 22' offset -1.5, -6; 
#set lmargin at screen lm
#set rmargin at screen rm
#set bmargin at screen bm
#set tmargin at screen bm + size * kk
set lmargin at screen lm
set rmargin at screen rm
set bmargin at screen bm + size * kk + gap
#set tmargin at screen bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1) + abs(y4-y3))) + gap
set tmargin at screen bm + size + gap

set yrange [y2:y1]
plot "d-band.dat" using 2:x2tic(1) title "Neutral"  linecolor rgb '#616161',   \
     "d-band.dat" using 3 title "Positive" linecolor rgb '#EF6C00',   \
     "d-band.dat" using 4 title "Negative" linecolor rgb '#039BE5',  

unset x2tics
unset xtics
#unset ytics
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
set key at 11, -18.3
set border 2+1+8
#set ytics nomirror
#set bmargin at screen bm + size * kk + gap
#set tmargin at screen bm + size + gap

#set lmargin at screen lm
#set rmargin at screen rm
set bmargin at screen bm
set tmargin at screen bm + size * kk
#set tmargin at screen bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y2) + abs(y4-y3)))

set yrange [y4:y3]

plot "d-band.dat" using 2:x2tic(1) title "Neutral" linecolor rgb '#616161',   \
     "d-band.dat" using 3 title "Positive" linecolor rgb '#EF6C00',   \
     "d-band.dat" using 4 title "Negative" linecolor rgb '#039BE5',  

unset multiplot
```

Comment: If you already know that the ytic distance should be 1, have you tried `set ytics 1`? Check `help ytics`. Or might this value vary for different plots and you want to have an automated setting identical for both plots?

Comment: @theozh, it does not solve the problem completely. As you have said, this value varies for different plots, and I want to have an automated setting identical for both plots. Because If I set ytics 1, then the space or division per ytic is not identical between the two plots in the given figure.

Comment: I think you need a set size for each plot.

"set size ratio 0.5"

should set the y-axis to half the length of the x-axis. I can't tell what ratios you need, but I can see both plots have the same ratio now.

Comment: @Ezio ok, I see. How do you (or the automated algorithm) decide depending on the data where to split the graph and how to set the ranges? It's not yet clear to me whether you want equal tic spacing but automated for different ranges (here: 1) or automated equal split ranges [0:8] and [12:20] or the two plots with (manually) given ranges [0:8] and [16:20], but with y-axes lengths proportionally to that scales? Probably, you want "simply" to cut out and hide (or shrink) a part of the graph, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution without multiplot... you could do something with nonlinear axis, check `help nonlinear`.
Since I don't have your data, I created some simpler data and plotted it just with boxes.

- you add a nonlinear mapping to your y-axis.
- for separating the y-axis you place a white rectangle on top of everything. This is not a nice workaround, but works for pixel graphics (e.g. like .PNG). You need to test, whether this will also work properly for .EPS, .PDF or other vector formats.

This can probably be fine tuned, e.g. to customize the gap and let the `-16` appear on the y-axis, etc.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.2.0)

```
### broken axis with equal ytic spacing using nonlinear axis
reset session

$Data <<EOD
A   -19.5
B    -4.0
C    -1.0
D   -18.3
E    -7.0
F    -5.0
EOD

y1 =  0.0
y2 = -8.0
y3 = -16
y4 = -20

set yrange[-y4:y1]
f(y) = y<y3 ? y-y3+y2 : y
g(y) = y<y2 ? y+y3-y2 : y
set nonlinear y via f(y) inverse g(y)

set x2tics out mirror
unset xtics
set grid y
set key noautotitle
set boxwidth 0.7
set style fill solid 0.3
set obj 1 rect from graph -0.01, first y2-0.1 to screen 1.0, first y2-0.5 fc "white" front fs noborder

plot $Data u 0:2:0:x2tic(1) w boxes lc var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @theozh this approach is helpful.

Comment: @Ezio if it solved your problem do not forget to check the check mark at the top left of the answer indicating that the question is answered.